# Поле "от кого" в письмах, отправленных функцией mail()

Tags: email, php

Помогите пожалуйста мне отправить письмо функцией `mail()`, и чтобы в поле **от кого** писалось Support. Как я это делал:

```
$header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n';
$header .= 'From: Support <support@gmail.com>\r\n';
```

Но в этом поле всё равно приходит адрес сервера ;( Если я поменяю местами:

```
$header = 'From: Support <support@gmail.com>\r\n';
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n';
```

То всё нормально подставляется, но письма приходят в аброкадабре( Как правильно это прописать, чтобы сообщение было на русском и от кого подставлялось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$header = "From: Support <support@gmail.com>\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf8\"\r\n"
```

в одинарных кавычках `\r` и `\n` не преобразуются в соответсвующие символы.

Answer (score 0):

[Попробуйте вот такое решение](http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=80&topic=1699&postid=1351847857#1351847857)